# What do I need to create an "Office" project in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ms-office, visual-studio-addins

I have Office 2007 installed(with .NET support checked everywhere) and VS 2008(with all updates).
My problem is that there is no Office category when creating a new project. What else do I need to create an "Office" project?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish again? Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Do you have the standard version of VS2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard edition of VS2008 does not contain the VSTO templates. You need the Professional version or above. Therefore, you will be limited to using the Shared Add-ins template for creating Office Add-ins.

> For an introduction to creating Office
>   add-ins using the Shared Add-in
>   project template, see the following KB
>   articles:
>
> - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302896
> - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302901
>
> If you go this route, and you want
>   your add-in to be used in a real-world
>   environment, you should strongly
>   consider also using a COM shim for
>   your add-in. For more details, see
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508939.aspx.
>   This article also has some potentially
>   helpful links to other topics about
>   managed COM add-ins.

Ref.: [VSTO templates missing in VS .Net 2008](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/f0262d75-770e-4b7c-95d8-53d7b071cf53)